# How to write predicate for file count using std::filesystem?

Tags: c++

I have such a method that count all the files by the given dir

```
std::size_t number_of_files_in_directory(std::filesystem::path path)
{
    using std::experimental::filesystem::directory_iterator;
    return std::count_if(directory_iterator(path), directory_iterator{}, [](auto) { return true; });
}
```

there is a predicate `[](auto) { return true; }`

The question is - how to write this predicate that counts only `.bmp` files?

I did it like this

```
return std::count_if(directory_iterator(path), directory_iterator{}, [](const std::filesystem::path&)
    { 
        if (path.extension() == ".bmp")
        {
            return true;
        }

        return false; 
    });
```

but I get an error

```
1> error C3493: 'path' cannot be implicitly captured because no default capture mode has been specified
```

Comment: `path` is the path to the directory as provided to the enclosing `number_of_files_in_directory` function. If you want your lambda's `const std::filesystem::path&` argument to have a name, you'll have to provide it with one and then use that in the body of the lambda.

Comment: I believe the correct term is "predicate", not "predicator".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to name your parameter.

Because the scope of the lambda has another parameter with the same name `path`, the compiler thinks you forgot to scope that variable in your lambda.

You could change the signature of your lambda to `[](const std::filesystem::path &path)`

But better is to not re-use `path` as a variable name inside the lambda, and pick something more descriptive like `file`.

Comment: I might try to pick a more descriptive name than `path`, which is already both a type and another variable in the same code. Maybe `file` or something?

Comment: @NathanPierson Added your suggestion to my answer!